# Find out what is mounting my external HD and change ownership?

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, automounting, ntfs, ownership

OS: Linux Mint 18.3.

I have an NTFS-formatted external HD which just gets automounted when I boot up. I'm just trying to find out what actually does that, and whether it's possible to set the ownership to root instead of the logged-in user.

(NB my understanding is that the ownership for an entire NTFS partition, all folders and all files, is set when you mount it and can't be changed using `chown`).

There is no mention of this partition in `/etc/fstab`. After doing a bit of searching I tried `sudo ntfs-config` and `sudo autofs`. Neither of these packages is as yet installed.

The reason for wishing to change to root is to help prevent inadvertent deletion of the files on this HD. The `Trash`/`Rubbish Bin` functionality is in fact working ***sometimes*** (sometimes pressing Delete actually causes a folder to disappear irretievably!). I just would prefer to mount it with `root:root` ownership if possible.

I also just want to know what mechanism in Linux is responsible for mounting.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested, I posted the same question on the Linux Mint forum and received some answers: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=310519&p=1751219#p1751219